# Deploying WAR-Application in JBoss Wildfly with unavailable DataSource?

Tags: java, jpa, jboss, wildfly

I have a web application which uses JPA persistence under wildfly 8.2.
The `persistence.xml` is connected to `<jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/myDS</jta-data-source>` which generally works fine.

BUT if I start the JBoss-Server *before* the Database-Server is ready, the web application doesn't get deployed with the following error:

```
BAS011411: Unexpected problem gathering statistics:    java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011477: Persistence unit 'my.war#myPU' is not available
```

My wish is that the application DOES get deployed (and throws an exception when is accessed) even when the DB-server is not available.
Is that possible?

My datasource-definition:

```
 <datasource jndi-name="java:/jdbc/myDS" pool-name="myDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb</connection-url>
                <driver>mysql</driver>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>15</max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>true</prefill>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>myuser</user-name>
                    <password>mypwd</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                    <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                    <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
                </validation>
            </datasource>
```

Steps to reproduce:

- Deploy an app with a "valid" datasource definition but keep the database server *offline*

Comment: Do you mean you've deployed your application before you've added the data source?

Comment: No, the datasource definition is present.... but think about rebooting all your servers and it might be possible that the (MySQL-)database server is not already up when the Wildfly server boots up... and THEN wildfly says "Persistence unit 'my.war#myPU' is not available"

Comment: The deployment shouldn't be processed until the data sources are added. If you're seeing an error about the data source not being available then it's either a configuration error or a bug.

Comment: I experience this as well and would like to find a solution.  Our servers are rebooted periodically and there are times that the database server does not come back online when WildFly tries to start the apps.  I will get app.war.failed and in it is a message 'Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/datasources/app'   So like cljk, I'd like users to be able to still access the successfully deployed web app but have a message state that the database is not available, and when the database server gets started properly, then the app should just work without having to app.dodeploy

Comment: @jeff exactly what I´m asking for. Me personally I´ve not yet found a solution directly - but the problem didn´t occur anymore (whatever reason) so I didn´t search anymore. 
If anybody finds a solution... I would be glad to hear.